# How to convert array of object(hasMany relationship data) to array of id?

Tags: ember.js, hasura

I wanted to get data and show it in UI. Here's how i write to get the "movies" data.

`let movies= yield this.store.findAll('movie');`

And I log the "movies". As the picture below shows that there's no data for "photos".

[image]

Here's the network:
[image]

I'm getting data back from hasura like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "movies": [
      {
        "id": "584db434-5caa-475e-b3ec-e98e742f0030",
        "movieid": "abc123",
        "description": "Penquins dancing in antactica",
        "photos": [
          {
            "id": "c4d2833a-4896-42b0-ae8b-0ab9fe71d1d4"
          },
          {
            "id": "e04697e3-21fe-4f0e-8012-443f26293340"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But Ember.js can't read and render the relationship data (photos). Is it the "photos" data should be like this?

```
"photos": [c4d2833a-4896-42b0-ae8b-0ab9fe71d1d4, e04697e3-21fe-4f0e-8012-443f26293340]
```

How can I convert it in Ember? or in Hasura?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? Are you just trying to show the data in the UI/Handlebars? Are you grabbing information through the model hook?

Comment: what adapter are you using? do have a way to interpret hasura-formatted data into the `{json:api}` standard format (what ember-data uses)? are you using ember-data? or are you using fetch?

Comment: @Cameron I've edited the question. Hope thats clearer

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli Im using restadapter. im not sure is there a way to format the data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for updating your question!

Since you're using ember-data, you'll need a custom adapter and serializer to form your data into the format that ember-data is expecting (since there are infinite numbers of ways APIs decide how to structure data).

More information on that can be found here:
https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-adapters/
and here: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-serializers/

Your data is fairly well structured already, so conversion *should* hopefully go well. Comment back if you have issues <3

Comment: Hi, I'm using RestAdapter and RestSerializer. But im not sure how to implement it. Should I convert the photos data to `"photos": [c4d2833a-4896-42b0-ae8b-0ab9fe71d1d4, e04697e3-21fe-4f0e-8012-443f26293340]`? So that ember can read that?

Comment: can you add your adapter and serializer code to your question?